# Adding celery queue at bootstep

Tags: python, celery

I want to make two things

1. I made a worker bootstep that loads configuration from remote.
2. I want to get a param from config and add a queue with set it at consumer queue name.

app.steps['worker'].add(LoadConfig)

works perfect

but i can't make a SetQueue boot step

simply my SetQueue now looks like:

```
class SetQueue(bootsteps.StartStopStep):

    requires = (Consumer, )

    def start(self, parent, **kwargs):

        parent.add_task_queue('q_name', exchange='q_name', routing_key='q_name')

app.steps['consumer'].add(SetQueue)
```

it doesn't work.

I think my problem is that i doesn't understand - at what moment(requires=(???, )) does queues can be added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Celery there are different "blueprints", where each blueprint is composed of multiple bootsteps.

The first blueprint to start is the Worker, which e.g. starts the execution pool,
the last blueprint to start is the `Consumer`, which connects to the broker and starts the
task consumer, among other things.

So your `requires` is not pointing to a bootstep, it's pointing to a blueprint.

I see that your bootstep adds another queue to consume from, so it would make more sense
for it to depend on the `Tasks` bootstep, which is required to be running if you want to call
`add_task_queue`.

```
class SetQueue(bootsteps.StartStopStep):
    requires = ('celery.worker.consumer:Tasks', )
```

You can see the startup components overview here:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/extending.html#blueprints

Also, with custom bootsteps registered you can generate a new version of this graph
using:

```
$ celery -A proj graph bootsteps | dot -Tpng -o steps.png
```